# Calculating great circle distance in r programming with high data resolution

Tags: r, geospatial, distance

I'm new to R programming but I'm calculating the great circle distance flown by a long haul airliner and I've tried `rdist.earth()` from the Fields package, `soDistsN1()` from the `sp` package and other commands. Plus I've pretty much exhausted Google in my search. It's easy to do this in Matlab but I can't seem to find a way in R.

The problem is when I increase the data resolution (amount of waypoints calculated) my total distance goes haywire. I'm guessing it is because of how I summarize the total distance between waypoints. Any ideas?

An example of what I've tried:

```
data <- read.csv("FDM_test_Flight.csv")
library(fields)
fix <- cbind(data$LON, data$LAT)
fix_2 <- window(fix, deltat=500) # every 500th position I have 25,540 position readings                      
gcd <- rdist.earth(fix_2, miles=FALSE, R=6371)
sum(gcd)
```

Comment: check out geosphere package btw

Comment: It will also help for people to test if you can paste the output from `dput(head(data))` into a code block in your question. Then we can copy/paste and recreate a portion of your data in R to check that your data is what it is supposed to be and that our code works properly. Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate them yourself using the formula for [Great Circle distances](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) like this...

```
r <- 6371 # radius of the Earth
data <- read.csv("FDM_test_Flight.csv")

# Convert to radians and make two vectors of point A and point B
x <- length(data$LON)
lon <- data$LON[1:(x-1)] * pi/180
lat <- data$LAT[1:(x-1)] * pi/180
lon2 <- data$LON[2:x] * pi/180
lat2 <- data$LAT[2:x] * pi/180

#Calculate distances
dist <- sum(acos(sin( lat ) * sin( lat2 ) + cos( lat ) * cos( lat2 ) * cos( lon2 -lon ) ) * r )
```

Since `r` is given in Km your great circle distances will be Km.

Answer (score 4):

`rdist.earth` computes the distance between *all* pairs, so by summing up the entire matrix you're not just getting the sum of the distances between successive observations.

```
library(fields)
lonlat <- matrix(-92:-80,c(1:7,6:1))
out<- rdist.earth ( ozone2$lon.lat)
sum(out[row(out)==col(out)+1])  ## add first off-diagonal
```

But @SimonO101's solution is more efficient: if you look at the guts of `rdist.earth` you'll see that's more or less what it's doing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you only sum the off diagonal matrix values (size one) from your gcd matrix you should get what you need. As Ben Bolker put above, rdis.earth() calculates the distance between "all pairing". 
Now how it works:
If you have, say, three locations: 1, 2 and 3. You need 
dist(1,2) + dist(2,3) 
the same pattern for any n points will hold.
So, these info are already in the rdis.earth. Just extract what you need and sum them up. Here- (sorry for the for loop)

```
sum(gcd) #but this is too large, it's summing all the pairings!


limit <- dim(gcd)[1] - 1

for(i in 1 :limit ){
  sum_off_dia[i]<- gcd_data[i,i+1]
}
sum(sum_off_dia)
```

Comment: how is this different from my solution except less efficient?  (The last line of code in my example adds up the off-diagonal values.)

Comment: fair enough.  I agree that my code is a bit more 'magical', and that in the short run `for` loops are easier to understand.  In the long run, vectorized solutions are (1) more efficient (sometimes much more efficient) and (2) generally more compact, which can help with code readability in its own way (e.g. compare `v=0; for (i in 1:nrow(m)) { for (j in 1:ncol(m)) v <- v + m[i,j] }` to `sum(m)` ...