# Association between two coordinates in R

Tags: r, geolocation, geospatial, distance

I have a problem with spatial data. 
I need to extract temperature data from a NetCDF file; then I need to associate this temperature at given latitude and longitude to another set of latitude and longitude contained in a different dataframe.
This is the code I used to extract my variables:

```
myfile <- nc_open(paste(wd, 'myfile.nc', sep=''))
timearr = ncvar_get(myfile, "time")  
temp <- ncvar_get(myfile, 'temp_srf')
lat <- ncvar_get(myfile, 'lat_rho')
lon <- ncvar_get(myfile, 'lon_rho')
dim(temp)

[1] 27 75 52         # which means: 27 longitude * 75 latitudes * 52 time steps
```

I chose to work on the first time step of temperature for now. So:

```
> t1 <- as.vector(temp[,,1])
```

Then I created a data.frame including lat, lon and temperature in the first time step:

```
lat1 <- as.vector(lat)
lon1 <- as.vector(lon)
df1 <- as.data.frame(cbind(lon1, lat1, t1))
head(df1)

    lon1    lat1     t1
1 18.15338  40.48656 13.96225
2 18.24083  40.55126 14.36726
3 18.32845  40.61589 14.53822
4 18.41627  40.68045 14.78643
5 18.50427  40.74495 14.88624
6 18.59246  40.80938 14.95925
```

In another data frame (df2) I have some random points of latitude and longitude, that I have to associate to the closest latitude and longitude of the previous data.frame:

```
> df2 <- read.csv(paste(id, "myfile.csv", sep=""), header=TRUE, sep=",")
> head(df2)

    LONs     LATs
1 14.13189 43.41072
2 14.13342 43.34871
3 14.09980 43.40822
4 14.05338 43.72771
5 13.91311 43.88051
6 13.98500 43.91164
```

I was thinking to get the distance between each point and get the lowest one, but I don't know how to do it. Not sure if there are other solutions.

Comment: There are multiple solutions, but it depends on if you have projected or planar coordinates. Projected are like lat-long you get on your mobile phone or GPS device (which I suspect you have) and are measured in angular degrees.

Comment: require(sp); ?spDistsN1

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming your data are projected coordinates, and that you need to calculate great circle distances. You can use a formula yourself (see [**my answer here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15570265/1478381)), or you can use `rdist.earth` from the package `fields`. For each entry in `df2`, calculate the distance from all entries in `df1`, find the index of the minimum distance in that vector, and use that index to select the appropriate row `df1` to assign temp to `df2`. It only takes one line (but it might be clearer to seperate the steps over a few commands):

```
require( fields )
df2["Temp"] <- df1[ sapply( seq_len( nrow(df2) ) , function(x){ which.min( rdist.earth( df2[x,] , as.matrix( df1[ c("lon1" , "lat1") ] ) , miles = FALSE, R = 6371 ) ) } ) , "t1" ]

And the results using your data:
df1
#         lon1     lat1       t1
#   1 18.15338 40.48656 13.96225
#   2 18.24083 40.55126 14.36726
#   3 18.32845 40.61589 14.53822
#   4 18.41627 40.68045 14.78643
#   5 18.50427 40.74495 14.88624
#   6 18.59246 40.80938 14.95925

df2
#         LONs     LATs     Temp
#   1 14.13189 43.41072 13.96225
#   2 14.13342 43.34871 13.96225
#   3 14.09980 43.40822 13.96225
#   4 14.05338 43.72771 14.53822
#   5 13.91311 43.88051 14.53822
#   6 13.98500 43.91164 14.78643
```

It looks like your distances are at least a Km apart (>300km in this data) so you should get good accuracy with the Great Circle formula. If they are smaller than 1km you may want to use the [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Answer (score 0):

Two formulas I like for getting the distance between two lat/long coordinates are the [Haversine formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) and [Vincenty's formula](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong-vincenty.html). The Haversine formula is a simpler formula that assumes Earth is a perfect sphere. You will probably get accuracy to a few feet. If you need a higher level of accuracy, try Vincenty's formula. It's spheroid based which attempts to account for Earth's imperfect sphere shape. The samples on the links aren't in R but it shouldn't be difficult to rewrite them in R.